# Error to create the Indexed View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create this View with Schemabinding:

```
CREATE VIEW RANKING_OPTIMIZATION_VIEW
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT USERS.[USER_ID],
         USERS.GAMERTAG,
         CLASSIFICATION.WIDGET_ID,
         CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATIONTYPE_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CLASSIFICATION.WIDGET_ID, 
                                        CLASSIFICATION.CLASSIFICATIONTYPE_ID 
                               ORDER BY CLASSIFICATION.[SCORE] DESC ) AS RANKING,
         CLASSIFICATION.WIN,
         CLASSIFICATION.LOSE,
         CLASSIFICATION.SCORE
  FROM   [dbo].[GMW_CLASSIFICATION] AS CLASSIFICATION
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[GMW_USERS] AS USERS
           ON USERS.[USER_ID] = CLASSIFICATION.[USER_ID]
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[GMW_WIDGET_GAMETYPES] AS GAMETYPE
           ON GAMETYPE.[WIDGET_ID] = CLASSIFICATION.[WIDGET_ID]
              AND GAMETYPE.[GAMETYPE_ID] = CLASSIFICATION.[CLASSIFICATIONTYPE_ID]
```

I got this error:
Cannot create index on view "GameRoomDev.dbo.RANKING_OPTIMIZATION_VIEW" because it contains a ranking or aggregate window function. Remove the function from the view definition or, alternatively, do not index the view.

Any ideas how to change the query??
Thanks

Comment: You need to remove the `ROW_NUMBER` function call. There won't be any way to replace it. There are [many restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions) on indexed views.

Comment: I know... But i want to change this query, put another mode to capture the current row by widget_id and classification_id, but i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Read following for the allowed things in Indexed View
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.100).aspx
you are i think using Rowset functions.

Comment: I know... But i want to change this query, put another mode to capture the current row by widget_id and classification_id, but i don't know how

Comment: Oh ok.I think you have to change your question heading to something like "Alternative for Row_Number Function so it can be used in indexed view"

Comment: How to Change it..? The Question... I must create another, i can't edit this question to another heading....

Comment: I am not that so good and neither has your database so that i could at-least try something. Best possible thing is to post sqlteam forums

Comment: Also read http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views